# Energy of a dipole?

Tags: electrostatics, energy, electric-fields, dipole

Suppose that we have a perfect dipole with $+q$ at $\vec{r}+\vec{d}$ and -q at $\vec{r}$, and that this dipole is in a uniform electric field $\vec{E}$,
 Then: 
\begin{equation}U=-\vec{p}\cdot \vec{E}.\end{equation}

First, what does a perfect dipole mean ? Then I don't really understand the solution of problem $4.7$ in the David J.Griffiths introduction to Electrodynamics which goal is to prove that $U=-\vec{p}\cdot \vec{E}$.
For me, the energy of a system of two point charges is equal to $\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}q\times(-q)\frac
{1}{d}$? But in the solution, it is written that the energy $U$ is given by: 
$$U=qV(\vec{r}+\vec{d})-qV(\vec{r}),$$ where $V$ is the electric potential. I don't understand where does this formula come from...

Comment: I don't have the question in front of me, but you might check the wording of the question.  I also don't understand your calculation of energy, but it seems you are calculating the electrostatic potential energy of two charges.  The question seems to be asking for something different:  the potential energy of a dipole in an electric field.  Note that your solution does not mention the external field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, we assume the dipole just exists.

By “energy of the dipole”, we’re not talking about the energy to *assemble* the dipole (the self energy), but rather the energy to *orient* the dipole in the external field.